# Can I express the size of some function whose 3arguments are equivalent to (x,y,z), by the density of color at each point on 3 dimension?

Tags: r

In the following program, is it possible to express the size of p[r0,gamma,a] at each point in 3 dimensions, where the X coordinate is r0, the Y coordinate is gamma, and the Z coordinate is a, by the intensity of the color?
And if I want to do that, what kind of code and how/where should I implement it?
Or is it impossible to that by R?
http://okadasan.com/S_P.R

I tried to use plot3d
But I notice it's impossible, because not 4 ones but only 3 arguments can be used in this plot3d.

#######################################
library(rgl)

p = array(1:72000, dim=c(20,36,100))
q = c(1:20)

k = 4187         # phase constant [rad/m] = (2*pi)/lambda =(2*3.14)/(1500/1000000)
f = 1000000   # frequency [Hz]
rou = 1.06      # density

for (r0 in 1:20)     # Depth [*5 mm]
{
for (gamma in 1:36)
{
for (a in 1:10)  # Radius of Daiphragm  [m]
{
a = a*0.0005
Jn_z = 0
for (m in 1:100)
{
z = k*a*sin(gamma*10)
P_Jn = (((-1)^m)/(factorial(m)*factorial(m+1)))*(z/2)^(2*m+1)
Jn_z = Jn_z + P_Jn
}
Imp<-complex(real=0,imaginary=2*pi*f*rou)
Phase<-complex(real=0,imaginary=2*pi*f-k*r0)

```
          # Sound Pressure 
          p[r0,gamma,a] = Imp*(a^2*5*exp(Phase))/(r0*(Jn_z/(k*a*sin(gamma*10))))
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code in the question (not a download link) and make this a reproducible example.

Comment: In addition to @jpsmith 's comment: What exactly is going wrong when you use `plot3d`? Any error message or unexpected output?

Comment: I attached the code directly.

Comment: Anyway. I would like to draw the size of the function composed of 3 arguments in 3 dimension, corresponding these arguments to coordinate of x, y, z each,  using the thickness (change) of color. I wonder if this is impossible...